# How can i change the current location in iphone 4s?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am using core location framework inside my app i have to ask that How can i change the current location in iphone 4s for testing of this function of core location framework:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation      
   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
```

inside this function i am sending the newLocation on server by hitting the specific link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options I think,

1) You can simulate locations using [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/faq/)

2) In xcode 4.2 you can simulate using debugger itself..

[image]

3) Or carry the phones with your app wherever you go.. sorry ;)

Comment: Thanks i tested in xcode 4.2 i changed the location in debugger and didUpdateToLocation method of core location framework gets called.its solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it using simulator in XCode4.2 with iOS 5.0.

In debug area, there are some predefined location that you can change when you running your app in simulator, you can also define custom location in GPX files. Here is a tutorial for how to add a custom location.

http://plainoldstan.blogspot.hk/2011/08/on-gpx-files-for-xcode-42.html